# Alamofire unacceptable content type json mysql

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am posting data to a mysql database using alamofire and I can see the data appearing in the database so the code is working. However, I don't like the error or notice I am seeing in Xcode console which says:

responseValidationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseValidationFailureReason.unacceptableContentType(acceptableContentTypes: ["application/json"], responseContentType: "text/html"))

I am not that familiar with Alamofire but it looks like the error is saying I am posting text/html and not json. But this isn't what I want, I want to post json. I am not sure if I need to use codable and encode the data first or what the issue is if there is actually an issue. Because my other thought is that .responseJSON is actually converting the parameters into json format and that's why the validation gives me that error because it is checking the data before it is formatted as json?

```
    let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:8888/mobile/bd_booking.php")

    let parameters: Parameters = [
        "firstName": namesTxt.text,
        "email": emailTxt.text,
        "contactNo": contactNoTxt.text
    ]


    Alamofire.request(url!, method: .post, parameters: parameters)
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
        .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                print("Success")
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
    }
```

Comment: You probably have to set the `Content-Type` to `application/json` in your request. For instance using `Alamofire.request(request)` constructor, and parametrise the request beforehand : `request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")`.

Comment: My bad it seems you have an error related on the `response` and not the `request`. Nevermind. Something you could try is to get rid of the `.validate(contentType: ["application/json"])` line, and print the `response` in the completion handler. You'll see the full answer that way

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I had a similar issue.

I resolved the error by reading this official section:
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#json-encoding

We need to append encoding parameters too while making the request. 
For example: 
[image]

I hope you'll be able to resolve the current issue by implementing this.

Comment: Thank you, I tried that but am still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try to use .validate(contentType: ["text/html"]) instead of .validate(contentType: ["application/json"]).

Another interesting feature in Alamofire is, .responseDecodable(of: YourModel.self){ response in
//no need to cast results just check for success and failure cases and enjoy :)
}